# Remove part of string by HTML img tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got this string that contains HTML code and somewhere in the middle there is an image tag.

```
var html = '<p><p>agsagsa</p><img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805">' + 
            '<img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA96540MF3480001F04325">hfhfdhfdhfd</p>' + 
            '<p>gfdhfdhfd</p>';
```

I need to find it by the src and remove it from the beginning to the end so from `<img src...` up to the closing tag.

I need to locate the right src as there is more than one in the string.

I can find the index of the right src but can't figure out how to remove it from the string by the closest `<img` on the left and closest closing tag on the right.

```js
var html = '<p><p>agsagsa</p><img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805">' + 
            '<img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA96540MF3480001F04325">hfhfdhfdhfd</p>' + 
            '<p>gfdhfdhfd</p>';
            
            
function findImg(imageSrc) {
  var src = html.indexOf(imageSrc);
  console.log('src = ', src);
}

findImg('/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805');
```

Could you review it and help me simplify it?

```js
var html = '<p><p>agsagsa</p><img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805">' + 
            '<img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA96540MF3480001F04325">hfhfdhfdhfd</p>' + 
            '<p>gfdhfdhfd</p>';
            
var originalSrc = '/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805';

var startOfSrcIndex = html.indexOf(originalSrc);
console.log('startOfSrcIndex = ', startOfSrcIndex);

var srcLength = originalSrc.length;

var openingTagIndex;

for(var i = startOfSrcIndex-1; i > 1; i--) {
  if(html[i] === '<') {
    openingTagIndex = i;
    break;
  }
}

var closingTagIndex;
console.log('srcLength = ', srcLength);

for(var i = srcLength; i < html.length; i++) {
  if(html[i] === '>') {
    closingTagIndex = i + 1;
    console.log('closingTagIndex = ', closingTagIndex);
    break;
  }
}

console.log('openingTagIndex = ', openingTagIndex);

var image = html.substring(openingTagIndex, closingTagIndex);
console.log(image);

var finalHtml = html.replace(image, '');
console.log('finalHtml = ', finalHtml);
```

Comment: Convert it into actual DOM nodes and use `.querySelectorAll()` or `.getElementsByTagName()` to find and remove image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to create a temporary element to insert the html into and `angular.forEach()` to loop through images to compare then `remove()` the match

```js
var imgUrl ='/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805'


var html = '<p>agsagsa</p><img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805">' + 
            '<img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA96540MF3480001F04325">hfhfdhfdhfd</p>' + 
            '<p>gfdhfdhfd</p>';
            
            
var div = angular.element('<div>').append(html);

angular.forEach(div.find('img'), function(el){
  if(el.src.includes(imgUrl)){
     el.remove()
  }
});

html = div.html()
console.log(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is a brilliant answer, using Angular functions too. Thank you.

Comment: Modifying html strings is best done using dom methods and since `angular.element` is a lite version of jQuery might as well use it to perform the task

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk have a look at my answer below to do it without using any other dependancies.

Comment: @LloydNicholson if it wasn't an angular app it would be simple to do same approach using `document.createElement()` and query image elements with dom methods like `querySelector()`

Comment: @charlietfl I have just seen the angular tag now but the question never specified Angular anywhere else other than in the one tag so I assumed basic javascript was needed. I used the code given from the question asker and helped him solve the problem.

Comment: @LloydNicholson just suggesting that using dom parser methods is typically best approach. No need to over-complicate it when there are better tools available

Comment: @charlietfl I've never used Angular before. I like to start at the ground level with an open Atom page and some code. It makes it more difficult to learn but more rewarding. I see what your point is though. I'll definitely check out Angular

Comment: @LloydNicholson same thing using native dom methods https://jsfiddle.net/5fzw7pge/. I only use angular since it was tagged as such implying that OP is working within an angular app

Comment: @charlietfl I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have got another alternative if you only want to use straight up Javascript code in your project without using Angular. See below.

```js
    var html =
      '<p><p>agsagsa</p><img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805">' +
      '<img src="/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA96540MF3480001F04325">hfhfdhfdhfd</p>' +
      "<p>gfdhfdhfd</p>";
    
    var originalSrc = "/Service/image.jsp?7D4D25E41ADA46ADE053480001826805";
    
    function replaceImgTags(source) {
      var startOfSrcIndex = html.indexOf(source);
      console.log("startOfSrcIndex = ", startOfSrcIndex);
    
      var srcLength = source.length;
    
      var openingTagIndex;
    
      for (var i = startOfSrcIndex - 1; i > 1; i--) {
        if (html[i] === "<") {
          openingTagIndex = i;
          break;
        }
      }
    
      var closingTagIndex;
      console.log("srcLength = ", srcLength);
    
      for (var i = srcLength; i < html.length; i++) {
        if (html[i] === ">") {
          closingTagIndex = i + 1;
          console.log("closingTagIndex = ", closingTagIndex);
          break;
        }
      }
      var image = html.substring(openingTagIndex, closingTagIndex);
    
      var finalHtml = html.replace(image, "");
    
      return finalHtml;
    }
    
    var newOriginalHtml = replaceImgTags(originalSrc);
    
    var newHtmlString = replaceImgTags(newOriginalHtml);
    console.log("New String is: " + newHtmlString);
```

This returns a value and then uses that value of the returned string of newHtmlString to log it to the console.